# Get definition of function and echo the code

Tags: powershell

I've defined a dynamic function in powershell, like this:

```
> function test { dir -r -fil *.vbproj | ft directory, name }
```

Then I can just type `test` and run that function, piping it to other commands, etc. Pretty handy.

Is there a way I can get the definition of the command? Can I echo out the code for my function `test`? (Without having to go back through my history to where I defined it?)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For a function called `test`:

```
$function:test
```

Or if the function name contains a hyphen (eg. `test-function`):

```
${function:test-function}
```

Alternatively:

```
(Get-Command test).Definition
```

Answer (score 7):

```
(Get-Command Test).Definition
```

That is how I normally get definitions.

Comment: In `$profile` `function def ($funcname) {
    (Get-Command $funcname).Definition
}`

Answer (score 7):

Both of these approaches - `${function:myFn}` or `(Get-Command myFn).Definition` - will only work for functions that have been created locally.

You also can see the definition of native functions like `Get-EventLog` (e.g.). with the [`CommandMetadata`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.commandmetadata?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) and [`ProxyCommand`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.proxycommand?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) commands in the [`System.Management.Automation`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) namespace like this:

```
using namespace System.Management.Automation

$cmd = Get-Command Get-EventLog
$meta = New-Object CommandMetadata($cmd)
$src = [ProxyCommand]::Create($meta)
$src | Write-Output
```

**See Also**: [Can we see the source code for PowerShell cmdlets?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20484505/1366033)